# Autobahn.js - subscribe doesn't work with websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket, autobahn

I'm using Ratchet WebSockets and Autobahn.js for two-way client-server communication. I've installed everything, opened the ports, it's been weeks (yes, literally weeks) and it still doesn't work. I think I've narrowed it down to Autobahn's subscribe method not working correctly.

What I'm using is a slight modification of the example code found here:

http://socketo.me/docs/push

Here is my client code:

```
<script>
    window.define = function(factory) {
        try{ delete window.define; } catch(e){ window.define = void 0; } // IE
        window.when = factory();
    };
    window.define.amd = {};
</script>
<script src="/apps/scripts/when.js"></script> 
<script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var conn = new ab.Session(
        'ws://light-speed-games.com:8080' // The host (our Ratchet WebSocket server) to connect to
      , function() {            // Once the connection has been established
            console.log('Connection established.');
            conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            });
        }
      , function() {            // When the connection is closed
            console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
        }
      , {                       // Additional parameters, we're ignoring the WAMP sub-protocol for older browsers
            'skipSubprotocolCheck': true
        }
    );
</script>
```

I believe the problem lies here:

```
function() {            // Once the connection has been established
                console.log('Connection established.');
                conn.subscribe('kittensCategory', function(topic, data) {
                    // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                    console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
                });
            }
```

The line `console.log('Connection established.');` does its job - it logs its message in the console. However, the `conn.subscribe` method does nothing. It doesn't matter if I change `kittensCategory` to any other string, it still does nothing. But `kittensCategory` is the only thing that makes sense here (see Ratchet's example code through the link above).

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is the output of ab.debug:

```
WAMP Connect autobahn.min.js:69
ws://light-speed-games.com:8080 autobahn.min.js:69
wamp autobahn.min.js:69
WS Receive autobahn.min.js:64
ws://light-speed-games.com:8080  [null] autobahn.min.js:64
1 autobahn.min.js:64
[0,"52cbe9d97fda2",1,"Ratchet\/0.3"] autobahn.min.js:64
WAMP Welcome autobahn.min.js:67
ws://light-speed-games.com:8080  [52cbe9d97fda2] autobahn.min.js:67
1 autobahn.min.js:67
Ratchet/0.3 autobahn.min.js:67
Connection established. client.php:15
WAMP Subscribe autobahn.min.js:74
ws://light-speed-games.com:8080  [52cbe9d97fda2] autobahn.min.js:74
kittensCategory autobahn.min.js:74
function (topic, data) {
                // This is where you would add the new article to the DOM (beyond the scope of this tutorial)
                console.log('New article published to category "' + topic + '" : ' + data.title);
            } autobahn.min.js:74
WS Send autobahn.min.js:72
ws://light-speed-games.com:8080  [52cbe9d97fda2] autobahn.min.js:72
1 autobahn.min.js:72
[5,"kittensCategory"]
```

Comment: You might set `ab.debug(true, true)` at the beginning (before doing anything else) and attach the log output here.

Comment: I placed that bit of code at the beginning (before initializing the conn variable) and the output has been appended to my question. I think the 'WS Receive' bit is suspicious because of the 'null' at the end.

Comment: As can be seen from the very last line, AutobahnJS sends a `SUBSCRIBE` message (http://wamp.ws/spec/#subscribe_message). If this is indeed the last line in the log, and you expect to receive an event, then something server-side is going wrong, since otherwise you'd see an WS Receive with `[8, "kittensCategory", something]` (http://wamp.ws/spec/#event_message).

Comment: I believe Apache is not listening to port 8080 after all, as I was unable to telnet to it from the server just now. Do you think that is in agreement with the log pasted above?

Comment: No. Since then, the `WELCOME` message `[0,"52cbe9d97fda2",1,"Ratchet\/0.3"]` would have not been received.

Comment: Ok, I think I got a bit confused myself here. It's not Apache that should be listening on port 8080, it's the Racthet push server, which I have running. You can find the code here, under the "Tying it all together" headline: [link](http://socketo.me/docs/push). As you see it's configured to listen on port 8080. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I neither use Apache nor PHP .. maybe ask on Ratchet mailing list ..

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem here

Comment: but for me i get the message @oberstet mentionned :[8, "kittensCategory", something]

Comment: But I can't do anyhting with it in js (same code as OP )